# Detecting if an integer can be writen as a multiply of given integers

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a set of given integers:

```
A[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 100, 500 }
```

1. I want to check if a given integer `T` can be written as a multiple of the numbers in `A[]`;
   EDIT CLARIFICATION:
   any number in A[] **can** be used.If used can be used only one time.
   EX 60 is a valid T.60=30*2.
   AlSO 90 is valid . 90=3*5*6
2. Check **which** numbers can form that integer `T`.
3. Also return the **2 closest** integers to the given `T` (that can be written that way) if the number `T` cannot be written as a multiple of that numbers.

Parts 2 and 3, I think I can sort out of my own if someone helps me with part 1.

I know this is an algorithmic question or even a mathematical one but if anyone can help, please do.

**NOT HOMEWORK. SEE COMMENT BELOW.**

### #

SOLUTION.
TY VERY MUCH FOR ALL ANSWERS.1 answer particulary (but the author choose to remove it and i don't know really why since it was correct.)
Ty author (don't remember your name.)

### #

Solution Code with a twist(The author's algorithm used multiple times one multiplier.This one uses multiplier only 1 time)

```
int oldT = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> used = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        while (T != 1 && T != -1) {
            oldT = T;
            for (int multiple : A) {
                if (!used.containsKey(multiple)) {
                    if (T % multiple == 0) {
                        T = T / multiple;
                        used.put(multiple, true); 
                    }
                }
            }
            if (oldT == T)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: this looks like you're quoting a homework question... if so please tag "homework"

Comment: No it's not a homework question.I'm working on a "Betting" android program of my own and the only allowed bets are multipliers of these numbers * 0.3 (euros).
So not a homework, but a feature to a program i'm working on.

Comment: It is **not** clear what you mean by a "multiply of given integers".  Should T be a product of some of the `A[]`? Can numbers be used more that once?  Alternatively, is it the sum of products?  E.g. 700 = 500 + 2 * 100.

Comment: How large can A get?  If it's not large, you can compute all subsets of it and multiply them to get a list of all possible 'bets', and then just do binary search on that.

Comment: He removed his solution because it doesn't work with some examples. Like A = [2, 6] and T = 6. You'll first divide T by 2, get 3 and get stuck. Sadly, bruteforce solutions sometimes fail :)

Comment: I think he wants to say "product", and that each element of `A` can be used at most once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If T is not very big (say, < 10^7), this is straight DP.

```
a[1] = true; // means that number '1' can be achieved with no multipliers
for (every multiplier x) {
   for (int i = T; i > 0; --i) {
      if (a[i] and (i * x <= T)) {
          // if 'i' can be achieved and 'x' is a valid multiplier,
          // then 'i * x' can be achieved too
          a[i * x] = true;
      }
   }
}
```

That's assuming every multiplier can be used only once.
Now, you can find decomposition of T if you have another array b[i] storing which multiplier was used to achieve i.

There's a lot of online content to get familiar with dynamic programming, if you have little time. It should give you idea how to approach such problems. For example, this one seems not bad
http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg

Comment: No not every multiplier must be used.That's the tricky one i can't get to find a solution.it can be 2 or 3 etc.Also T represents "money" so yes it's <<<10^7.
Ty for the link i'll give it a try.

Comment: _No not every multiplier must be used_  Exactly. If valid multipliers are 2 and 3, then 'a' will have 'true' for 1, 2, 3 and 6.

Comment: Also note that the first problem in the link is very similar: it just uses addition instead of multiplication.

Comment: The idea to use dynamic programming is a good one, but this isn't a very efficient implementation.  I guess that's left to the reader to fill in.  (For example, storing a 'max true so far', never starting above T/x since that won't pass the condition anyway, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

If the user can select n*(one of those numbers), then note that you have the primes 2, 3, 5, and 7, so if your number is divisible by 2, 3, 5, or 7, then divide that out, and then you have n*(that one).

If you have to multiply the numbers by each other, but can do so multiple times, then note again that all of your numbers factor into powers of 2, 3, 5, and 7.  Check if a bet is divisible only by these (divide each out until you can't divide out any more, then see if you're left with 1) and count the number of times you've divided by each one.

If you have to multiply the numbers by each other *without* replacement, then again find the prime factorization and remove from the list whichever number makes the powers present the most even.  If you manage to remove all the multiples, you're done.

In all but the last case, the numbers that can be bet is very dense, so you can find the nearest just by going up or down and checking again.  In the last case, searching for something near could be kind of tricky; you might just want to form a table of possible (low) bets and suggest something from that, assuming that users aren't going to bet 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*10*15*....

Comment: direct "divided them all" strategy isn't going to work. If you have only multipliers 2 and 6 and T = 6, then you'll first divide T by 2, get 3 and get stuck.

Comment: Yes i thought about pre-forming a sorted tables for all possible bets but the size whould be huge (talking for a mobile device).
Thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: @Nikita - This is why I say "whichever number makes the powers present the most even".  It's a heuristic that will usually work; certainly not always for arbitrary sets of numbers, but pretty well for the given set.

Comment: @weakwire - The table is not huge--you have yes or no answers on each of 16 items, which is 2^16 entries.  If you throw away the impossibly large ones, the table's even smaller.  It's the same strategy as Nikita suggested, except more efficient to compute since you are guaranteed to find every solution in 16*2^16 steps, whereas in Nikita's you have 16*T where T is your upper bound.